# Centering text in html button

Tags: html, button

I am trying to center text on a button, and am running into a wall. Right now, my code looks like:

```
.plus {
    background-color: #4CAF50; /* Green */
    border: none;
    color: white;
    padding: 1px 1px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
  }
  .plus1 {border-radius: 50%;}
```

I tried changing font size, but that did nothing at all. I have been editing the padding settings, and the image below is the closest I could get, as shown:

[image: plus button]

But, it still is not centered! How do I move my text up?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it! I changed the line height to 5px, and it now looks like: [fixed button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuFjP.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your code (aside from a larger font-size) looks fine in a stand-alone page:

```css
.plus {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 1px 1px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
}

.plus1 {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<a class="plus plus1">+</a>
```

This means there's other CSS interfering on your page if you get something that looks like your image.

Comment: I was trying to use the thick plus character (&#x2795) instead of just a plus. Does that make a difference? I'm also displaying it within a table.